# SOAP Login Error: com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: unable to find end tag at

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, java, wsdl

I have a Java rest api i built using version 37 of partner wsdl and version 37 of metadata wsdl.

Today i generated new jars using version 39. However, my api throws an error if i use `https://Login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/39` but still works with `https://Login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37`

What could I be missing?

Comment: Ideally the URL should be `https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/39.0`. Note the 39**.0** in the API version.

Comment: Can you include the full exception message and stack trace? Then Callout request XML would also be useful if you can find it. I suspect the response is telling you there is something wrong with the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely due to the change in the `GetUserInfoResult` that was introduced in v38.0 of the Partner API WSDL.

The `orgDefaultCurrencyLocale` element was added just after the `orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode` element in the `GetUserInfoResult` complexType.

When you switched from v37.0 to v39.0 of the API the response started to include this new element. It would appear that you Java code can't currently handle the new field in the response.